# Preg match with request

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regular expression to find out whether the string prefix to the number (_number) and if there is to get this number

```
//Valid

if (preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9_])+([_])+([0-9]).html$/i', 'this_is_page_15.html'))
{
  $page = 15;
}

//Invalid

 if (preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z0-9_])+([_])+([0-9]).html$/i', 'this_is_page15.html')) // return false;
```

Comment: Why do you feel regex is the best solution here?  You are basically only interested in getting the part of the string after the last `_`. This is very easy to do with simple string manipulation (i.e. `strrpos()` and similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you would probably want some kind of function to do this.  `preg_match` will return a `1` if it finds a match, a `0` if no match is found, and `FALSE` if there is an error.  You need to supply the 3rd parameter `$matches` to capture the matched strings (details here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

```
function testString($string) {
    if (preg_match("/^\w+_(\d+)\.html/",$string,$matches)){
        return $matches[1];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So `testString('this_is_page_15.html')` will return `15`, and `testString('this_is_page15.html')` will return `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = 'this_is_page_15.html';
$page;
if(preg_match('!_\d+!', $str, $match)){
    $page = ltrim($match[0], "_"); 
}else{
    $page = null;
}
echo $page;
//output = 15
```